# Spring Security alters request URI

Tags: jsp, spring-security, uri

I integrated Spring Security into an existing Spring Boot project (Version: 1.5.3.RELEASE).

Before the integration, we've got our redirect informations from a request via getRequestURI in a preHandle method which extends HandlerInterceptorAdapater.

The Request URI is correctly pointing to their path (for example: /admin/login).

After the integration, the request URI is pointing to the complete path of the jsp.

In addition, we've registered a ContextUtil class to ConfigurableApplicationContext for further URI checkings. In this class, we fetch the request like this:

```
public HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest()
{
    final ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = 
    (ServletRequestAttributes) 
    RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    return servletRequestAttributes.getRequest();
}
```

but the URI is also to its "physical path" under `/WEB-INF/`

For example: 
GET Request is pointing to `/WEB-INF/pages/admin/admin_login.jsp`:

My `WebSecurityConfig` Class is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        //jeden Aufruf akzeptieren. Authorisierung und 
    Authentifizierung von Spring Security wird nicht genutzt
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
}

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", 
    "/img/**", "resources/*", "/WEB-INF/**").and().debug(true);
    }
}
```

Relevant `applicationContext.xml` parts:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/resources/" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="de.abc.xyu.zzz.interceptor.RedirectInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Debug Log from Spring Security:

Request received for GET '/admin/login':

> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@70ad489
>
> servletPath:/admin/login pathInfo:null headers:  host: localhost:8081
>   connection: keep-alive cache-control: max-age=0 user-agent:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36 upgrade-insecure-requests: 1 accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>   referer: http://localhost:8081/admin/login accept-encoding:
>   gzip, deflate, br accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
>   cookie: JSESSIONID=AE07684D485DA698F1AA4DFE056D5B3A;
>   JSESSIONID=0819B947A685FE3362F23E39CE999D3B
>
> Security filter chain: [   WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
>   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter   HeaderWriterFilter   CsrfFilter
>   LogoutFilter   RequestCacheAwareFilter
>   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
>   AnonymousAuthenticationFilter   SessionManagementFilter
>   ExceptionTranslationFilter   FilterSecurityInterceptor ]
>
> ---
>
> [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO  Spring Security Debugger -
>
> ---

Request received for GET '/WEB-INF/pages/admin/admin_login.jsp':

> SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@2eac9514]
>
> servletPath:/WEB-INF/pages/admin/admin_login.jsp pathInfo:null
>   headers:  host: localhost:8081 connection: keep-alive cache-control:
>   max-age=0 user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94
>   Safari/537.36 upgrade-insecure-requests: 1 accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>   referer: http://localhost:8081/admin/login accept-encoding:
>   gzip, deflate, br accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
>   cookie: JSESSIONID=AE07684D485DA698F1AA4DFE056D5B3A;
>   JSESSIONID=0819B947A685FE3362F23E39CE999D3B
>
> Security filter chain: [] empty (bypassed by security='none')

Why is the request pointing to its physical path under /WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp instead of its resolved path and how can we achieve it, that we get the "correct" URI?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: can you tell me where you accessing this url in the controller ?

Comment: @Manoj, yes, in an AbstractTagController, @ Configurable

Answer (score 1):

Eventually this worked for me:

```
final ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = 
    (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

System.out.println("REQUEST URI: " +
     servletRequestAttributes.getRequest()
         .getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"));
```

That gives the real request URI, not its "physical path" under /WEB-INF/.